# Dispatch native DOM event in Webdriver.io

Tags: selenium, testing, integration-testing, webdriver-io

Hi is there a way how to dispatch DOM events on elements?
Like for example in runtime JS would be achieved by:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("some-id")
var event = new Event('change');
el.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `execute` method: http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/execute.html

```js
.execute(function() {
    var el = document.getElementById("my-id");
    var event = new Event('change');
    el.dispatchEvent(event);
})
```